# Both side margin in latex

Tags: pdftex, margins

I am writing a report in latex and I want to write in both side. I am pretty successful to give both side (odd and even) margin. My problem is that I want first three page of the report in one side and then I need both side. What command should be used? Please comment

Comment: i take it you don't know where the first 3 page breaks are (so \cleardoublepage is not the solution).

Answer (score 1):

In case you meant you want blank pages for the first three even pages.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcount{\SScount}

\newcommand{\SSrepeat}%
{\cleardoublepage
 \global\advance\SScount by -1
 \ifnum\SScount>0 \afterpage{\SSrepeat}%
 \fi}

\newcommand{\singleside}[1]% #1 = number of single-side pages to create
{\global\SScount=#1\relax
 \ifnum\SScount>0 \afterpage{\SSrepeat}%
 \fi}

\begin{document}
\singleside{3}%
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}‎‎
\lipsum[1-20]
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=5cm,twoside}
\lipsum[1-20]
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```